# Difference between frozen and canned fruit paste

Tags: ingredient-selection

I want to make a recipe requiring strawberry fruit paste. I went on a web site of cooking supplies seller, and they have two options for fruit paste, simply "fruit paste" and "frozen fruit paste". The site says that the frozen paste is made from 90% fruit, but has no ingredients description for the normal one (says it's made only from fruits and natural food coloring).

When going on the manufacturer webpage of the non-frozen product, it says that it's in a tin can.

What are the differences between the two, and what are the advantages disadvantages of each, regardless of the price?

The brands being sold are (to clarify what the seller means by frozen and "normal" are) Boiron for frozen and Fabri for normal.

Comment: I hope it's ok that I wrote brands of products to better explain my question, if it's not allowed, I'll remove them.

Comment: How is the non-frozen type sold? Chilled? Canned? The latter requires cooking unlike chilled or frozen.

Comment: @ChrisH, [this](https://en.fabbri1905.com/professionals/pastry-chefs/product-categories/lines/delipaste-fruit-ca.kl) is the product on the producer's site, I'm not sure how to use it, I need to make with it compote that will be part of a cake, but I would like to know the differences in general and when in one more apropreate over the other.

Comment: In other words, it's been canned ("package"="tin") so it's been cooked.  I suggest you update your question as you're asking about the difference between a frozen and a canned product, which is likely to be significant.